# Azure Timezone difference: Application insights vs Diagnostic

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights, azure-diagnostics, azure-analytics

- Timezone in Diagnostics is displayed as UTC by default but cannot
  find a way to configure.
- Timezone in Azure Analytics (query) can be    configured and is by
  default UTC Timezone
- In Application insights however is local time(of who ever uses
  it) and cannot be configured. And worst, it is not displayed on the screen which timezone it is.
- In Blob storage file(logs) also it is not clear which Timezone it is(assume it to be UTC)
- In Activity log a new term is specified along with the date...wait for it.. GMT!(why?)

This is really annoying while trying to fix a production issue. Can all the time-zones be configured in one place(or at least timezones named)?

Comment: it really depends on specifically which charts in which places in the portal.  there isn't really a single place to set it.  which specific places aren't showing UTC or you want to display UTC?

Comment: It is mentioned in the question

Comment: no, you mentioned "in application insights".  application insights has a ton of things, metrics explorer, search, workbooks, analytics, appmap, etc. which specific thing in application insights?

Comment: There is a [suggestion (2 years old) with about ~50 upvotes](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/223579-azure-portal/suggestions/33965440-add-a-setting-to-select-the-timezone-to-be-used-ac) to allow selecting timezone to display dates within Azure Portal.

Comment: @JohnGardner I know this is quite old, but what about "Performance" and "Failures" sections on App Insights? Do you know if it's possible to display and filter telemetry using UTC dates? Right know it's displaying same date as my computer.

Comment: the performance and failures blade also doesn't have a setting for local vs utc, i'll forward this SO to them.

Comment: What about using a userscript to change the time? There are plenty of examples online, but I don't have any Javascript skills or knowledge to do this myself.....

Comment: Manipulating html? We are talking about internal query results.

Comment: Well, I was referring to the graphs shown in App Insights and Diagnostics in Azure, which is similar to what your question is about. See here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69661209/javascript-for-converting-utc-time-to-local-time-in-azure/69661445#69661445