# Javascript for converting UTC time to local time in Azure

Tags: javascript, azure

When looking at certain resource graphs in Azure, the time shown is in UTC instead of local time and it doesn't seem like there's a way to change this. I've looked around for userscripts and extensions to try to change the time to local time, but to no avail.

I'm not a programmer, I don't really know how to code in Javascript, but I think having a userscript for this would be handy. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Below is a link to some sample code I copied from Chrome's DevTools:
https://pastebin.com/Gef8GAfD

```
< g class = "highcharts-axis-labels highcharts-xaxis-labels"
data - z - index = "7"
aria - hidden = "true" > < text x = "116.60508146921"
style = "color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;white-space:nowrap;fill:#666666;"
text - anchor = "middle"
transform = "translate(0,0)"
y = "259"
opacity = "1" > 10 - 20 12: 00 < /text><text x="201.94062413698" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;white-space:nowrap;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="259" opacity="1">10-20 16:00</text > < text x = "287.27616680475"
style = "color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;white-space:nowrap;fill:#666666;"
text - anchor = "middle"
transform = "translate(0,0)"
y = "259"
opacity = "1" > 10 - 20 20: 00 < /text><text x="372.61170947252" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;white-space:nowrap;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="259" opacity="1">2021-10-21</text > < text x = "457.94725214029"
style = "color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;white-space:nowrap;fill:#666666;"
text - anchor = "middle"
transform = "translate(0,0)"
y = "259"
opacity = "1" > 10 - 21 04: 00 < /text><text x="543.28279480806" style="color:#666666;cursor:default;font-size:11px;white-space:nowrap;fill:#666666;" text-anchor="middle" transform="translate(0,0)" y="259" opacity="1">10-21 08:00</text > < /g>
```

[image]

Comment: Issue resolved by these 2 extensions (also available for Chrome):

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/localise-timezones/
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/localise-times/

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you need to understand that the dashboard and data you are seeing on the Azure Dashboard are not editable as it is just simple HTML code that is used to represent the data coming from the system behind it. if that system is sending the data in the UTC format then this dashboard is going to show in that format only. you might have to change the setting of the Azure portal to reflect the local timezone.

Check this [https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/working-with-time-zones-in-the-admin-interface-of-azure-hosted-kentico-projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-time-zone?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/change-time-zone?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page

Comment: I disagree. You can definitely edit the HTML code, I just did it using Chrome DevTools. I just don't know how to do it with Javascript. If I have a working Javascript, I can just load it as a userscript into Greasemonkey or something like that. - https://imgur.com/5iAwwog.

Comment: Also, take a look at this. I don't understand the code, but this guy is changing the values of the clock dynamically. The clock seconds are changing dynamically and I've tested it and it works - https://www.htmlgoodies.com/javascript/javascript-bookmarklets-greasemonkey/

Comment: also, the links you've posted are for Azure DevOps. That's not the same platform as Azure portal itself. I already went through the settings in Azure portal and there isn't a time related setting to adjust. I'm talking about resource graphs generated from the "Diagnose and solve problems" in e.g App Service, or resource graphs from Azure Monitor. Those are all showing as UTC time without any filter or setting to change them to a different time.